# Show that if the smallest prime factor $p$ of the positive integer $n$ exceeds $n^{\frac{1}{3}}$ then $\frac{n}{p}$ must be a prime or 1.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I am really having a problem understanding the proof of this question. Let me write the proof and i will explain my question

Let $p$ be the smallest prime factor of $n$. Assume that $p > n^{\frac{1}{3}}$
Then
$p > n^{\frac{1}{3}} \Rightarrow p^{-1} < n^{-\frac{1}{3}} \Rightarrow np^{-1} < nn^{-\frac{1}{3}} \Rightarrow \frac{n}{p} < n^{\frac{2}{3}}$.

Let $m = \frac{n}{p}$, and assume that it is greater than $1$. Notice that $m$ cannot have a prime factor less than $n^{\frac{1}{3}}$. However

$n^{\frac{1}{3}} = \sqrt{n^{\frac{2}{3}}} > \sqrt{m}$

Therefore, $m$ does not have a prime factor less than $\sqrt{m}$. Hence, $m$ is a prime.

I really dont understand this proof and Why does $m$ not have a prime factor less than $n^{\frac{1}{3}}$? If someone can explain to me this proof i would really appreciate it ! thanks

Comment: $n^{\frac 13}$ is smaller than the smallest prime factor of $n$. If $m$ has  a prime factor $p$ smaller than $n^ {\frac 13}$, then $p$ would be a prime factor of $n$ smaller than $n ^ {\frac 13}$, which is a contradiction. Hence, $p$ must be bigger than $n ^ {\frac 13}$, but then the argument above shows this is not possible.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. It is asking about a particular step of a particular proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does $m$ not have a prime factor less than $n^{\frac{1}{3}}$?

Since $m$ is constructed as $m=\frac np$, and $p$ is given as a factor of $n$, we know that $m$ is an integer factor of $n$ also. **In this section of the proof** we have $m>1$, and obviously any factor of $m$ is also a factor of $n$. By the initial premise, since no prime factor of $n$ is less than $p$, it is also true that no prime factor of $m$ is less than $p$, either.

Since $\sqrt m < n^{1/3}$, $m$ cannot either be a prime square or indeed have two factors itself (since one of them would then have to be less than $n^{1/3}$)- therefore $m$ must be prime.

Comment: Thank you very much. That cleared it out for me really appreciate it man